# Copy contents of bash script to new bash script

Tags: bash

My job is installing multiple RaspPi's and they all need to be set up the same way, with a couple bash scripts, some installed programs and a cron that I wrote. Is there a way I can write one script to `echo` or `printf` the contents of the other bash scripts into the new Pi's?

Can I just do this?:

```
echo "$(cat myfile.sh)" > newbash.sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst you can use the line from your question it's quite inefficient as you're redirecting your script through two pipes. You can simplify it by just using (as @Wimm pointed out):

```
cat myfile.sh > newbash.sh
```

However, if you're installing the scripts I'd suggest you look into using the [`install`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/install) command instead as this gives you finer control over the process by letting you set the permissions and UID/GID for the file and so on. Using `cat` will not copy *any* of metadata for your script; `cp` is a little better but you'd probably need extra commands like `mkdir -p`, `chown` and `chmod` to get thing just right. With `install` you could say something like:

```
install -Dp -v -o root -g staff -m 0755 myfile.sh /path/to/install/at/newbash.sh
```

This will...

- create any missing directories along the destination path (`/path/to/install/at`)
- make a copy of `myfile.sh`, called `newbash.sh`, at the destination
- set the timestamp of `newbash.sh` to be the same as `myfile.sh`
- change the owner of `newbash.sh` to `root` and the group `staff`
- set the file permissions to `0755` (or `-rwxr-xr-x` if you prefer)

Comment: I might've used the word "install" incorrectly in my explanation. Would `cat` or `cp` create the file under the current user's permissions? I would hate to use `install` and then not be able to run it without escalating considering these Pi's are designed to be mostly hands off.

Comment: Sure, use whatever user and group you like with `install`: `-o pi -g pi` for example. I didn't mean to imply that using `cp` is *wrong* only that there may be a better tool available with more control should you need it. I believe you can get the same outcome by using `cp -p myfile.sh newbash.sh` https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cp`(copy) or `cat`:

```
cp myfile.sh newbash.sh
cat myfile.sh >newbash.sh
```